# Should I store False as Null in a boolean database field?

Tags: database-design, null

Let's say you have an application that has a boolean field in its `User` table called `Inactive`.

Is there anything inherently wrong with just storing false as null? If so can you please explain what the down side should be? I have discussed this with someone a few months ago and we both agreed it shouldn't matter as long as you do it consistently throughout the app/database. Recently, someone I know was emphatic that "true" `true` or `false` should be used, but they didn't really give an explanation as to why.

Comment: [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) `Null is a special marker used in Structured Query Language (SQL) to indicate that a data value does not exist in the database` This is the accepted wisdom and you shouldn't redefine what Null means in your application. It will be confusing to everybody else working with your code.

Comment: Why would you even WANT to do this? Why not just use a non-nullable bit field and set the default to false if that is the behavior you want instead of confusing the issue with a tri-state field?

Comment: Real-world example of why that's a very bad idea:  `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = FALSE` doesn't give the results you expect.

Comment: It's not a matter of "if you do it consistently throught the app/database" but will you and at what cost.

Comment: Consider using an int column with a default of 0 rather than boolean.  This way if new conditions arise (perhaps a 'pending' state, for example), you dont have to alter the database structure.

Comment: But if you store false as null how are you going to store FILE_NOT_FOUND?! (http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx)

Comment: At least in (Msft) SQL Server, NULL is best interpreted as not an absence of value, but as an UNKNOWN quantity (could be true or false, or 0, or 1, or 'hello' - yes, the type can be inferred in a particular case) - you just do not know what the value is, you cannot reason about a probability of it having any value - it is unknown. That would explain why just about anything that gets mixed with NULL (Unknown), also becomes NULL (unknown). UNKNOWN is not the same as the absence of value, or false. Even if other vendors treat null slightly differently, why not make the only logical choice?

Comment: Why distort reality? Why not simply store false as false?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> Is there anything inherently wrong with just storing false as null?

Yes.

> If so can you please explain what the down side should be?

NULL is not the same as False.

By definition, comparisons (and logic) that involve NULL should return values of NULL (not False).  However, SQL implementations can vary.

`True and NULL` is NULL (not False).

`True and NULL or False` is NULL (not False).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Three-valued_logic_.283VL.29

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966426.aspx

Comment: Succint explanation on why NULL is the value representing the absence of value.

Comment: the first day of my first development job involved debugging and fixing an error like in this question/answer, reminiscence +1

Comment: Comparisons *that need the nulled value* return null.  MySQL and PostgreSQL (the only systems i have access to test at the moment) both return False for `select false and null`, and True for `select null or true`, and even return true for `select false and null or true`.  The truth tables for `AND` and `OR` make the null side unnecessary to determine the whole expression's value.  If it weren't so, you couldn't say `x = 0 or x is null` as a condition.

Comment: @cHao:  The `is` operator is usually seen as an exception to the "no comparison with null" rule.  It's defined as being unlike the other operators.  The "And" and "Or" short-circuits are often confusing because of the way that queries with OR's are transformed to make the OR effectively a short-circuit operator that doesn't simply evaluate both sides.  It should be looked at as an optimization, not a general principle.

Comment: Note that the very article you linked to says that if the `null` is irrelevant to the logic (as is the case in `whatever OR TRUE` or `whatever AND FALSE`, where no value of `whatever` can change the condition), then the expression returns a value.  It's not an optimization; it's *how 3-valued logic works*.  Any DBMS that insists on returning `UNKNOWN`/`NULL` for those expressions is fundamentally broken.

Comment: I added the http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966426.aspx that seems to show all NULL values for logic operators that involve NULL.

Comment: I'd argue that returning true or false when null is involved fundamentally broken.  NULL means unknown.  True AND NULL evaluates to NULL because you can't come up withe answer.  It might be true, it might be false, you don't know.  And that's the point.

Comment: @Andy: That i might not have argued with.  `True AND NULL` you can't know, because both sides have to be true in order to return true, and you don't have a value for one of them.   Same with `False OR NULL`, because both sides would have to be false in order to return false.  The examples first chosen were just really bad for making the point. But even then, if you stick with AND and OR, you end up with a system where `NULL` could stand in for `False`.  Where the system falls down is with operations like `XOR`, where *both* sides always affect the return value.

Comment: @S.Lott, but doesn't storing null instead of false save some space??

Comment: @Bludream: For booleans, a nullable field can actually take *more* space, depending on the DBMS.  (It's a negligible amount in nearly all cases, though.) A boolean can be represented in a single bit...but a *nullable* boolean has three possible values (true, false, and null), and thus needs more than one bit.

Comment: @S.Lott thx for your answer - but can databases store null in a boolean field type?

Answer (score 18):

By allowing nulls in a boolean field, you are turning an intended binary representation (true/false) into a tri-state representation (true, false, null) where your 'null' entries are indeterminate.  The 'null' value is neither appropriately 'true' nor 'false.'  What reason would you have to augment your representation to be inaccurate?

Even if you decide on a pattern such as this and do it consistently throughout your application, that does not make it okay. You'll end up in a situation where it is not clear to fresh eyes why that pattern is in place or, more likely, you'll end up in a situation where that pattern is inadvertently broken.

Answer (score 6):

What others have said.   3 possible values is not a boolean.

But you may have a legitimate need for 3 values. Such as (true, false, unknown). Even if this is the case, if you are into ultra-normalization you will not allow any null values at all. Instead you'll store a true boolean in another table with a 1 to 1 relation. A null value could be produced in a query by a "failed" outer join, not by a physically stored null value.

Comment: outside the realm of my boolean question why would true false unknown be bad if you used null to do it? Beyond my question are nulls generally to be avoided? Why?

Comment: @Ominus: Nulls are generally to be avoided if you're a purist.  If used as they were meant to be used (as "there's no value here" rather than as a fakey-fake `false`), then they have their place.  If they didn't, they wouldn't exist.  The alternative, as mentioned, is basically having a whole other table with just the primary key of your row and a single boolean (or int, or varchar, or what have you). For each and every field that you'd otherwise make nullable.  While relationally pure, it's too convoluted for most purposes.

Answer (score -3):

Is `bool?` a boolean type? No. It is of type `Nullable<T>` where `T` is boolean. A nullable boolean can have 3 values: true, false and null. To use `bool` or `bool?` depends on your requirement. There could be legitimate reason where you may need to use null but a type that smells like binary but you do not know the answer. In above example, `User.IsActive` seems clear cut. User is active or not. As a system, it might want to know if a user is active or not. There should not be 'maybe'. But think about something like a feature flag. Is the feature turned on? The answers could be yes, no, or not sure. You may have a business rule that spells out only show the button when flag is set to true. One may argue bool is by default false so why create nullable bool? Inverse the requirement: are you going to set all the values in the datasource to true?

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?